# Pandas assign values of a column of dataframe to value of another dataframe if values of two dataframe columns match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (which do not have the same number of rows)

dfA contains two columns "CCLE_ID" and "Name" amongst other unimportant ones

dfB contains two columns "CCLE ID" and "Cell line" amongst other unimportant ones.

Right now, dfB['CCLE ID'] values are set to 0.

What I want to do is compare all the values in `dfA['Name']` column and `dfB['Cell line']` column.  They are all strings and stand for the shorthand name of cell lines.  If a value for `dfA['Name']` and `dfB['Cell line']` column matches, then I want to replace the value 0 of `dfB['CCLE ID']` column with the string from `dfA['CCLE_ID']` column of that matched cell name.

I am honestly so lost as to how to do this (pandas beginner).

dfA

```
    CCLE ID Cell line   Cancer Query    Cancer Label    Score
0   0        CAOV4      OV              yes             0.604027
1   0        KURAMOCHI  OV              yes             0.592132
2   0        OVSAHO     OV              yes             0.586126
```

dfB

Comment: Could you provide some date sample and result as code ?

Answer (score 0):

First we presume dfA and dfB have the same number of rows because if they don't, then it's more complicated and you have two choices: either reshape the dataFrames to have the same number of rows, or use other Python libraries to perform the transformation.

Based on this initial presumption that the data Frames have the same number of rows, I'm going to try and break this down for you step by step.

With the two dataframes, `dfA` and `dfB`, start by merging the data. You can remove the extra columns from dfB later.

To merge the dfA columns into dfB for simplicity, add two columns dfaName and dfa_CCLE_ID.

```
dfB['dfaName'] = dfa['Name']
dfB['dfa_CCLE_ID'] = dfa['CCLE_ID']
```

Then use [pandas.dataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to conditionnally transform your data.

```
dfB['CCLE_ID'] = dfB[['dfaName','Cell line', 'dfa_CCLE_ID']].apply(lambda x: x['dfa_CCLE_ID'] if x['dfaName']==x['Cell line'] else x, axis=1)
```

A nice extra could be to use a [dataframe mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to generate and see comparison. It is a good step to take to view and test your data transformation. In this example, create an extra column in dfB with true/false values for the comparison.

`dfB['column_matcher'] = dfb['dfaName']==dfB['Cell line']`

Comment: Oh I will update the original post- there are a TON of cell line names in dfA['Name']... not all of them match the names in dfB['Cell line'], so they don't have the same number of rows DX

Comment: np.where would be my go-to for tasks like this.

Comment: @SydneyGhoreishi since it sounds like the  dataFrames are not the same number of rows, you may also find dataFrame.join to be useful. Something like `my_new_dataframe = dfB.set_index('Cell line').join(dfA.set_index('Name'), lsuffix='_dfb', rsuffix='_dfa'))` See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html